# Texto sobrescrevendo o header

Tags: c#, vb.net, itextsharp

Marquei a tag `C#` pois praticamente todos os exemplos encontrados na internet estão nessa linguagem e "traduzir" para `vb.net` é bem simples.

Meu *report* baseado no [iTextSharp](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp) é dinámico. Possui um *header* com as informações base e **duas** tabelas geradas dinamicamente.

Um dos meus problemas é que quando a tabela vai pra uma nova página ela simplesmente sobrescreve o *header*.

O outro problema é que eu preciso repetir o *header* da tabela se caso ela for para uma nova página, isso tanto para a primeira quanto para a segunda tabela.

Apesar de vários itens serem desnecessários para a pergunta, segue abaixo código na integra.

```vb
    Dim IDCompromisso = CType(HttpContext.Current.Session("IDCompromisso"), Integer)
    Dim CompromissoAtual = GetCompromisso().Where(Function(y) y.ID = IDCompromisso).FirstOrDefault()

    Dim nome As String = "report" + Date.Now.ToString().Replace(".", "").Replace("/", "").Replace(" ", "").Replace(":", "") + ".pdf"
    Dim pdf As New Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate())
    Dim path = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "\reports\" + nome
    Dim writer As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdf, New FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
    pdf.Open()
    CreateHeader(pdf)
    Dim evH As New HeaderF
    writer.PageEvent = evH
    pdf.Add(New Phrase("Produtos: "))

    Dim CountLoop = 0
    Dim ValidarItens As New List(Of CompromissoInfo)
    ValidarItens.Clear()
    For Each A In GetCompromissoInfo()
        If (GetValidarDataCompromisso().Where(Function(b) b.Vencimento = A.IDVencimento And b.Compromisso = A.CompromissoID And b.Item = A.ItemID).Count() > 0) Then
            ValidarItens.Add(A)
        End If
    Next
    For Each A In ValidarItens.OrderByDescending(Function(b) b.DT_VENCIMENTO).GroupBy(Function(B) B.IDVencimento)
        CountLoop = CountLoop + 1
    Next

    Dim pdfTable As New PdfPTable(CountLoop + 4)
    pdfTable.TotalWidth = 100
    CountLoop = 0
    pdfTable.DefaultCell.Padding = 3
    pdfTable.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT
    pdfTable.DefaultCell.BorderWidth = 1
    pdfTable.AddCell("Produto")
    pdfTable.AddCell("Código")
    pdfTable.AddCell("Qtd. Embalagem")
    For Each A In ValidarItens.OrderByDescending(Function(b) b.DT_VENCIMENTO).GroupBy(Function(B) B.IDVencimento)
        CountLoop = CountLoop + 1
        Dim cell As New PdfPCell(New Phrase(A.FirstOrDefault().DT_VENCIMENTO.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")))
        pdfTable.AddCell(cell)
    Next
    pdfTable.AddCell("Quantidade Total")

    Dim ValidarItensLista As New List(Of CompromissoInfo)
    ValidarItensLista.Clear()
    For Each A In GetCompromissoInfo()
        If (GetValidarDataCompromisso().Where(Function(b) b.Vencimento = A.IDVencimento And b.Compromisso = A.CompromissoID And b.Item = A.ItemID).Count() > 0) Then
            ValidarItensLista.Add(A)
        End If
    Next

    Dim QuantidadeGeral = 0

    For Each C In ValidarItensLista.GroupBy(Function(EX) EX.ItemID)
        pdfTable.AddCell(C.Select(Function(a) a.DESCRICAO).FirstOrDefault())
        pdfTable.AddCell(C.Select(Function(a) a.Codigo).FirstOrDefault())
        pdfTable.AddCell(C.Select(Function(a) a.EMBALAGEM).FirstOrDefault())
        Dim QTDTotal = 0
        For Each A In ValidarItensLista.OrderByDescending(Function(b) b.IDVencimento).GroupBy(Function(B) B.IDVencimento)
            Dim Validar = 0
            For Each X In A
                If X.ItemID = C.FirstOrDefault().ItemID And C.Where(Function(h) h.ItemID = X.ItemID).Select(Function(t) t.IDVencimento).Contains(X.IDVencimento) Then
                    pdfTable.AddCell(ConverterQuantidade(X.QTD_ITEM))
                    QTDTotal = QTDTotal + X.QTD_ITEM
                    Validar = 1
                End If
            Next
            If Validar = 0 Then
                pdfTable.AddCell("0")
            End If
        Next
        pdfTable.AddCell(ConverterQuantidade(QTDTotal))
        QuantidadeGeral = QuantidadeGeral + QTDTotal
    Next

    pdf.Add(pdfTable)

    pdf.Add(New Phrase("Resumo: "))

    pdfTable = Nothing
    pdfTable = New PdfPTable(4)
    pdfTable.TotalWidth = 100
    pdfTable.DefaultCell.Padding = 3
    pdfTable.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT
    pdfTable.DefaultCell.BorderWidth = 1

    pdfTable.AddCell("Nº Parcela")
    pdfTable.AddCell("Data de Vencimento")
    pdfTable.AddCell("Valor em " + CompromissoAtual.Moeda)
    pdfTable.AddCell("% Desconto")

    Dim ValorTotal = 0
    Dim Parcela = 0
    Dim CountFor = 0
    ValidarItens.Clear()

    For Each A In GetCompromissoInfo()
        If (GetValidarDataCompromisso().Where(Function(b) b.Vencimento = A.IDVencimento And b.Compromisso = A.CompromissoID And b.Item = A.ItemID And A.DT_VENCIMENTO = b.Data).Count() > 0) Then
            ValidarItens.Add(A)
        End If
    Next

    Dim Valores As New List(Of Single)
    Dim ValoresData As New List(Of Single)

    Dim Quantidade As New List(Of Integer)
    Dim Depurar As New List(Of String)


    Dim ValoresArray As New List(Of Single)
    Dim QuantidadeArray As New List(Of Integer)
    For Each A In ValidarItens.OrderByDescending(Function(c) c.DT_VENCIMENTO).GroupBy(Function(B) B.IDVencimento)

        For C As Integer = 0 To A.Count() - 1
            Dim Valor = (A(C).VLR_ITEM.ToString())
            Dim Desconto = ((A(C).VLR_ITEM.ToString() / 100) * A(C).DESCONTO)
            Dim QuantidadeItem = (A(C).QTD_ITEM)
            Dim Total = (Valor - Desconto) * QuantidadeItem
            QuantidadeArray.Add((A(C).QTD_ITEM))
            ValoresData.Add(Total)
        Next

        Depurar.Add("Quantidde = " + ValoresData.Count().ToString() + " Valores = " + ValoresData.Sum().ToString())
        Valores.Add(ValoresData.Sum())
        ValoresData.Clear()
        CountFor = CountFor + 1
        Quantidade.Add(QuantidadeArray.Sum())

    Next

    For Each Y In ValidarItens.OrderByDescending(Function(a) a.DT_VENCIMENTO).GroupBy(Function(Z) Z.IDVencimento)
        Parcela = Parcela + 1
        pdfTable.AddCell(Parcela)
        pdfTable.AddCell(Y.FirstOrDefault().DT_VENCIMENTO.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
        Dim ValorAtual = Valores((Parcela - 1))
        If Not ValorAtual.ToString().Contains(",") Then
            ValorAtual = ValorAtual + ",00"
        End If
        pdfTable.AddCell(ConverterMoeda(ValorAtual))
        pdfTable.AddCell(ConverterMoeda(Y.FirstOrDefault().DESCONTO))
    Next

    pdf.Add(pdfTable)

    pdf.Close()
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path)
```

Classes responsável pelo *header*

```
Public Class HeaderF
        Inherits PdfPageEventHelper
        Public Overrides Sub OnStartPage(ByVal writer As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter, ByVal document As iTextSharp.text.Document)
            CreateHeader(document)
        End Sub
    End Class

    Public Shared Function CreateHeader(ByVal document As iTextSharp.text.Document)
        Dim CompromissoAtual = GetCompromisso().Where(Function(y) y.ID = CType(HttpContext.Current.Session("IDCompromisso"), Integer)).FirstOrDefault()
        document.Add(New Paragraph("Número do Compromisso: " + CompromissoAtual.ID.ToString))
        document.Add(New Paragraph("Agente: " + CompromissoAtual.Agente.ToString))
        document.Add(New Paragraph("Safra: " + CompromissoAtual.Periodo.ToString))
        document.Add(New Paragraph("Origem de Faturamento: " + CompromissoAtual.OrigemFaturamento.ToString))
        document.Add(New Paragraph("Moeda: " + CompromissoAtual.Moeda.ToString))
        document.Add(New Paragraph("Data de Emissão: " + CompromissoAtual.DataEmissao.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")))
    End Function
```

**Resultado**

Página 1:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Página 2:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Perdoem a poluição nas imagens mas sou obrigado a fazer isso.

Comment: Vejo onde estabelece a palavra `Produtos:`, mas onde está definido as outras informações do *header* - `Número do Compromisso`, `Agente`, `Moeda`, etc.

Comment: Estava faltando. Acabei de adicionar

Comment: Polua mais a imagem! Se algum mal-intencionado quiser ler os dados, acho que ele pode conseguir em alguns lugares.

Answer (score 1):

Me inspirando com várias respostas a [essa pergunta do en.SE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18996323/add-header-and-footer-for-pdf-using-itextsharp), e mesmo nunca tendo usado o [itextsharp](/questions/tagged/itextsharp), creio que poderia fazer assim:

- Insere o conteúdo não no `OnStartPage()`, mas sim, no `OnEndPage()`.
- Quando faz uma nova página, vai ter que ter certeza que tenha *margins* suficientemente grandes para o header

Especificamente, [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18999087/1245766) do Bruno em inglês resume o problema, e dá sugestões de como fazê-lo se baseando em alguns exemplos. Segue-se uma tradução maladequada:

#### Original

> Adding headers and footers is now done using [page events](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=204). The examples are in Java, but you can find the C# port of the examples [here](http://tinyurl.com/itextsharpIIA2C05) and [here](http://tinyurl.com/itextsharpIIA2C06).
>
> Make sure you read the documentation. A common mistake by many developers have made before you, is adding content in the `OnStartPage`. You should only add content in the `OnEndPage`. It's also obvious that you need to add the content at absolute coordinates (for instance using `ColumnText`) and that you need to reserve sufficient space for the header and footer by defining the margins of your document correctly.

#### Tradução

> Adicionar headers e footers é feito utilizando [eventos nas páginas](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=204). Os exemplos são em Java, mas poderá encontrar a portagem ao C# dos exemplos [aqui](http://tinyurl.com/itextsharpIIA2C05) e [aqui](http://tinyurl.com/itextsharpIIA2C06).
>
> Leia a documentação. Uma falha comum que muitos desenvolvedores fizeram antes de você, é adicionar conteúdo na função `OnStartPage`. Deve-se adicionar conteúdo apenas na função `OnEndPage`. Também é óbvio que precisa-se adiconar o conteúdo com coordenadas absolutas (por exemplo, usando `ColumnText`) e que precisa reservar espaço suficiente para o header e footer por definir as margens do seu documento corretamente.